# how to do "press enter to exit" in batch

Tags: batch-file, rake

I am using rake to build my project and I have a build.bat file similar to this:

```
@echo off
cls
rake
```

When I double click on build.bat the dos window pops up and shows all the progress but closes itself when the task is finished. Is there way to do a Console.ReadLine so that user can get a chance to see the log?

Thanks.

Updated:

I've tried below but didn't work. not sure why.

```
@echo off
cls
rake
pause
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Default interpreters from Microsoft are done in a way, that causes them exit when they reach EOF. If rake is another batch file, command interpreter switches to it and exits when rake interpretation is finished. To prevent this write:

```
@echo off
cls
call rake
pause
```

IMHO, call operator will lauch another instance of intepretator thereby preventing the current one interpreter from switching to another input file.

Answer (score 90):

```
pause
```

will display:

> Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: sorry, didn't realise rake was another batch file.

Answer (score 14):

```
@echo off
echo something
echo Press enter to exit
set /p input=
```

Answer (score 10):

My guess is that `rake` is a batch program. When you invoke it without `call`, then control doesn't return to your `build.bat`. Try:

```
@echo off
cls
CALL rake
pause
```

Answer (score 5):

```
@echo off
echo Press any key to exit . . .
pause>nul
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this snippet:

```
@echo off
echo something
echo.
echo press enter to exit
pause >nul
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Oops... Misunderstood the question...

Pause is the way to go

### Old answer:

you can pipe commands into your patch file...

try

```
build.bat < responsefile.txt
```