# Test a windows batch file using python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, batch-file

I have created a batch windows batch file. The batch file runs an test.exe. i have used subprocess.popen to run the batch file using python. The batch file runs in a different window and the batch file runs a test.exe. The test.exe that the batch file runs in different windows says "Press any key to continue ". Can i pass the keystrock using python

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r'start cmd /c C:\test.bat', shell=True)
p.wait()
print 'done'
```

Comment: can you provide sample for test.bat as well ?

Comment: you would need some sort of interprocess communication. giving the two process have the same process father, I guess it's feasable.

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458636/how-to-do-press-enter-to-exit-in-batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is little that Python can do directly for your requirements, but Windows contains everything you need, and WinAPI functions are available from Python through the ctypes module of the standard library.

Here you need to :

- find the handle to the window hosting the child command
- send a single char (for exemple enter key) to that window

According to the way you start your batch and assuming a standard Windows installation, this should do the trick:

```
# find the window handle from the windows title (should be FindWindowA for bytes in Python 2)
hwnd = ctypes.windll.User32.FindWindowW(None, r'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe')
if hwnd == 0:
    raise ValueError("Window title not found")

# send a Return to that window (0x102 is WM_CHAR and 0x0D is VK_ENTER)
ctypes.windll.User32.PostMessageW(hwnd, 0x102, 0x0d, 1)
```